# Question about table partitioning in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am facing a problem with my partitioned table, and any help would be appreciated. Let's assume I have a table called A that is partitioned by the date field A_date, and this table contains billions of rows. Additionally, I have another table called B, which has a date field B_date and only a few hundred rows. For the purpose of this example, let's say all the values in B_date are "2023-05-01."

If I perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM A
```

BigQuery (BQ) states that it will process more than 1TB of data, which is expected given the large number of rows.

If I perform this query instead:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A_date >= "2023-05-01"
```

BQ states that it will process less than 1TB of data. This is also expected since I'm using the A_date partitioning and filtering by a specific date.

However, if I execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A_date >= (SELECT B_date FROM B LIMIT 1)
```

BQ states that the query will process the same amount of data as if I weren't using a WHERE condition, even though the result of "SELECT B_date FROM B LIMIT 1", in my case, is the same as "2023-05-01."

Initially, I thought it might be an estimation issue with BQ. However, I ran both queries (the last two) and checked the "query results" tab, which also showed a difference in the bytes processed.

Could someone help me with this issue? I'm trying to reduce the costs of my queries, but I'm unable to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the partition pruning.
When you filter with the exact date, the data consumption is less because you are querying a specific range. But when you query using a select statement, because the value can be dynamic, the entire table is scanned.

The reference for this can be found in this doc -
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#use_a_constant_filter_expression

You can declare a variable to get the date and use that variable to filter the date and it would give you results similar to

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A_date >= "2023-05-01"
```

To make use of partition, you can do the following:

```
DECLARE dateB TIMESTAMP;
SET dateB =  (SELECT B_date FROM B LIMIT 1);
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A_date >= dateB;
```