# Increased cost in BigQuery when adding an additional condition to a partitioned query

Tags: google-bigquery

a few days ago, I asked a question about optimizing my BigQuery query ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76271226/question-about-table-partitioning-in-bigquery/76271369#76271369)), and now I have encountered a related issue. I have noticed that when I perform the following query on my table A partitioned by the date column A_date:

```
DECLARE dateB TIMESTAMP;
SET dateB =  (SELECT B_date FROM B LIMIT 1);
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE A_date >= dateB;
```

It works fine and incurs lower costs due to utilizing partition on the column A_date. However, when I add another condition to the query, like this:

```
DECLARE dateB TIMESTAMP;
SET dateB =  (SELECT B_date FROM B LIMIT 1);
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE A_date >= dateB
AND A_another_column IS NOT NULL;
```

I observe that the processed bytes increase significantly, similar to when the partitioned column is not used in the WHERE clause. Can someone help me understanding why this happens and how I can query the table using both conditions without incurring higher costs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is BG filters the table by A_another_column first. It might think there are few records with A_another_column IS NOT NULL and prioritize A_another_column filter over A_date.

You may explicitly put the filtering order using a subquery:

```
DECLARE dateB TIMESTAMP;
SET dateB =  (SELECT B_date FROM B LIMIT 1);
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM A 
  WHERE A_date >= dateB
)
WHERE A_another_column IS NOT NULL;
```